# Closed form formula for non homogenous recurrence relation $f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Im looking for a closed form formula for the recurrence relation $f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + 1$, with $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=1$ and I'm at a loss. I realize that the homogeneous part is the Fibonacci sequence and I know the closed formula for that, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Z transform could help here.

Comment: You just need to find a particular solution - for example if you want to use the method of undetermined coefficients, the general theory suggests you should guess a particular solution of the form $f(n) = C$ a constant and then solve for $C$.

Answer (score 2):

You could define $g(n) = f(n) + C$, so that $f(n) = g(n) - C$. Then your recurrence becomes
$$
g(n) - C = g(n-1)-C + g(n-2) - C + 1
$$
i.e.
$$
g(n) = g(n-1) + g(n-2) - C + 1
$$
By picking $C = 1$, you see that $g$ satisfies the Fibonacci recurrence, albeit with different initial conditions.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I'm very new to solving these types of problems, and I could use a little clarification as to how this helps. So from there would I set up a system of equations using $f(n)=a((1+sqrt(5))/2)+b(((1-sqrt(5))/2) - c$?